# While placing order from Magento using paypal express checkout no content is displayed under "Your order summary section"

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.6

I am using **Website Payments Pro Payflow Edition (includes Express Checkout)** in Magento for paypal payments.

I am using Magento 1.6.2.0 community edition

But when I am redirected to the paypal site there is no detail of order item is visible under "Your order summary section"

[image]

What could be the possible reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your Magento settings for Express Checkout settings( Payflow Edition) , you have selected the **"Transfer Cart Line Items" to "Yes"** . You can refer the below screen shot :

[image]